# SVG icons cannot be loaded when using Angular2+ InMemoryWebAPI

Tags: angular, icons, angular-material, in-memory-database

When configuring the InMemoryWebAPI SVG icons cannot be loaded using

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataService, {dataEncapsulation: false}),
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CustomMaterialModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    matIconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('~/../assets/mdi.svg'));
  }
}
```

I tried to configure with apiBase parameter but without success.

Console: Error retrieving icon: undefined

The InMemoryWebAPI must ignore other urls outside API URL scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set passThruUnknownUrl option as 'true' to allow the unknown requests to pass through so that we can reach the actual assets by URL.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataService, {dataEncapsulation: false, passThruUnknownUrl: true}),
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CustomMaterialModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    matIconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('~/../assets/mdi.svg'));
  }
}
```